# Selecting a stable operating point in a core loss vs temperature graph

Tags: induction, ferrite

Not a native english speaker so please bear with me.

I want to build an Inductivity of 10uH for a sinewave current (50kHz, 0.5A RMS) and calculate the magnetic resistance . Magnetic Flux should stay at 200mT. I can select a 3F3 core and have the core loss vs temperature graph but i need to pinpoint a stable operating point. What confuses me is the frequency next to the 200mT magnetic flux on the graph. My sinewave has 2x higher frequency than the one on the graph, which value do I need for my calculation ?

Task is to find the right air gap for the core

I can select models with one of the following Al (nH) values:

40+-3% 
25+-3%
800+-25%

This is how I wanted to proceed, first I want to calculate the power loss by multiplying the core loss (first finding the right operating point) with the effective core volume (215mm^3), afterwards I can use R = U^2/P to calculate the magnetic resistance with Ul = wL*Irms

for the air gap i can use following formula to first calculate the windings L*I=N*B*A

afterwards I can calculate the Al value with Al = L/N^2 and select the right one.

[image]